# How to make a Magento extension to replace prototype.js w/ an alternate version in adminhtml only

Tags: magento, prototype, adminhtml

I need to call an alternate js/prototype1_6_0_3.js file into my admin only, and keep the original js/prototype.js for the user/customer front-end. I had to qickly upgrade the original js/prototype.js file to 1.7.0.1 b/c of an issue that popped up when IE10 did one of its auto-updates.

Currently my extension causes the admin to be mostly blank and very broken.
can someone point out what I'm doing wrong.
thanks.enter code here

Here is what I'm trying to do:

app\design\adminhtml\default\default\layout\adminprototypeversion.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
  <adminhtml>
    <reference name="head">
                <action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>prototype/prototype.js</name></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype1_6_0_3.js</script></action>
    </reference>
  </adminhtml>
</layout>
```

app\code\local\Alphacard\Adminprototypeversion\etc\config.xml

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Alphacard_Adminprototypeversion>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Alphacard_Adminprototypeversion>
    </modules>
        <adminhtml>
          <layout>
            <updates>
              <Adminprototypeversion>
                <file>adminprototypeversion.xml</file>
              </Adminprototypeversion>
            </updates>
          </layout>
        </adminhtml>
</config>
```

app\etc\modules\Alphacard_Adminprototypeversion.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Alphacard_Adminprototypeversion>
            <active>true</active>`enter code here`
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Alphacard_Adminprototypeversion>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your app\design\adminhtml\default\default\layout\adminprototypeversion.xml

You should be able to just rename the `<adminhtml>` node to `<default>`

Magento already knows it's for "adminhtml" because of the config.xml layout update in your module being declared within the "adminhtml" area.